# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in C while working with Bucket Sort

Tags: c

I have written a program in C for bucket sort:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define M 100

void insertion_sort(int arr[], int n){
    int i, j, k;
    for(i=1;i<n;i++){
        j=i-1;
        k=arr[i];
        while(j>=0 && arr[j]>k){
            arr[j+1]=arr[j];
            j=j-1;
        }
        arr[j+1]=k;
    }
}

int max(int arr[], int n){
    int max=arr[0];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(arr[i]>max)
            max=arr[i];
    }
    return max;
}

void bucketsort(int arr[], int n){
    int i, j, idx=0, *ptr, **bsort;
    int len=sizeof(int *)*n+sizeof(int)*n*n;
    bsort=(int **)malloc(len);
    int len1=n*max(arr, n);
    ptr=(int *)malloc(len1*sizeof(int));
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        *(ptr+i)=0;
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        int bindex=n*arr[i];
        bsort[bindex][*(ptr+bindex)]=arr[i];
        *(ptr+bindex)+=1;
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(*(ptr+i)>0)
            insertion_sort(bsort[i], *(ptr+i));
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<*(ptr+i);j++)
            arr[idx++]=bsort[i][j];
    }
    printf("The sorted array:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[M],n,i;
    char op[1];
    do{
        printf("Enter no of elements: ");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        printf("Enter array elements:\n");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
        bucketsort(arr,n);
        printf("\nDo you want to go again?(Y/N):");
        scanf("%s", op);
    }while(op[0]=='Y');
}
```

However, when I run the code, and give the necessary input, it gives me:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Why is this so? What sort of changes do I have to make in my code?
I've tried debugging on GDB, and it shows an error at the line

```
bsort[bindex][*(ptr+bindex)]=arr[i];
```

I don't understand why it should be so, since I have already written a max function for the same.

Comment: Apart from the bug you have encountered so far, there is an additional bug in the call `scanf("%s", op);` because the `op` buffer is only large enough to store 0 characters plus a null terminator. Typing any input will cause a buffer overflow.

Comment: @IanAbbott so even if I type a single character ('Y' or 'N'), it will give me an overflow?

Comment: Yes, unless `scanf` encounters end-of-file while looking for the start of the string, it will overflow the single-character `op` buffer.

Comment: On that line, what is bsort, what is bindex, what is bsort[bindex], what is ptr, what is *(ptr+bindex), what is arr, what is i? Do they all have sensible values? gdb can tell you, use the `print` command

Comment: `int **bsort` is pointing to uninitialized memory from `malloc`, so `bsort[bindex]` will be an invalid `int *` pointer value (even if `bindex` is in range, which it might not be), and `bsort[bindex][something]` is dereferencing an invalid pointer.